# i have firebase error when calling the serve function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\crypto project\crypto-back-end\functions> firebase serve

=== Serving from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\crypto project\crypto-back-end'...

!  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "13"
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\user\Desktop\crypto project\crypto-back-end\functions" for Cloud Functions...
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
!  functions: Cannot find module './tsconfig.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js
!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Comment: If you have a bug to report with the Firebase CLI, I suggest reporting it with your specific details to reproduce the error on GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, to improve your experience please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).